# What is a good way to match a part of a line using command line tools?

Tags: regex, command-line

I want to match a part of a line for example in the sentence:
"The super id=42 or something."

I want to return the number 42.

echo "The super id=42 or something" | grep -o 'id=[0-9]+' | sed 's/id=//'

Would return the correct answer, but is there a more elegant way of solving this, for example by using only one tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something quick and simple, that's perfectly fine.  You could do it all in one command/statement with `perl` but `grep` + `sed` like that should work  just fine.

Is this part of a larger toolchain/application or is it just for your own ad hoc needs?

Comment: It's really just for a script, but I've ran into this sort of situation quite a few times, and I wondered if there is a tool that can do the following: /id=([0-9]+/\1/ without too much extra code.

Answer (score 0):

The —or rather, a— perl version would be

```
echo "The super id=42 or something" | perl -ne '/id=(\d+)/ and print "$1\n"'
```